# spring amqp RPC copy headers from request to response

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm looking for a way to copy some headers from the request message to the response message when I use RabbitMq in RPC mode.

so far I have tried with `setBeforeSendReplyPostProcessors` but I can only access the response and add headers to it. but I don't have access to the request to get the values I need.

I have also tried with the advice chain, but the returnObject is null after proceeding so I can't modify it (I admit I don't understand why it is null... I thought I could get the object to modify it):

```java
    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();

        simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.setAdviceChain(new MethodInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
                Object returnObject = invocation.proceed();
                //returnObject is null here
                return returnObject;
            }
        });
        simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer.configure(simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory, connectionFactory);
        return simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
    }
```

a working way is to change my method annotated with @RabbitListener so it returns a Message and there I can access both the requesting message (via arguments of the annotated method) and the response.

But I would like to do it automatically, since I need this feature at different places.

**Basicaly I want to copy one header from the request message to the response.**
this code do the job, but I want to do it through an aspect, or an interceptor.

```java
    @RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue"
            , containerFactory = "simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory")
    public Message<MyResponseObject> execute(MyRequestObject myRequestObject, @Header("HEADER_TO_COPY") String headerToCopy) {
        MyResponseObject myResponseObject = compute(myRequestObject);

        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(myResponseObject)
                             .setHeader("HEADER_RESPONSE", headerToCopy)
                             .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Message<?>` return type support was added for this reason, but we could add an extension point to allow this, please open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues).

Contributions are welcome.